# std::map<string,int> default initialization of value

Tags: c++, initialization, std

This piece of code seems work well, with default value for they `value_type` (`int`) as 0; does it work for all cases?

```
std::map<std::string,int> w;
for (const auto& t: str)
   w[t]++;
```

What about double?
  map? default 0.0?

Comment: I cannot understand what you are actually asking. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The below answers are very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this code would work for any type of the key, including `double`. The reason this works is that the non-const `operator []` returns a *reference* to the value at the key, not a copy of that value. It is that reference to which the `++` operator gets applied.

The code fragment that you show works as follows:

- For each key `t` of type `string` in the `str` container,
- The map `w` is searched for the given key
- Since the entry is not there, a new one gets inserted into the map
- Since the key of the entry is known, but the value is not, a default (*value-initialized*, e.i. `0` for `int`) object for the value gets created
- A reference to the newly created object (in this case, `int&` initialized to zero) is returned to the caller
- The `++` operator is applied to the reference returned from the `[]`, which changes `0` to `1` (or `0.0` to `1.0`, etc.)

Comment: I see. Thanks. This is actually my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `a default object for the value gets created` , could you explain, why int is initialized to 0? AFAIC, default 'constructor' for `int` does not specify any particular value and the value expected to be undefined

Comment: @Alexey It is important to distinguish between default initialization and value initialization for an `int`. If you write `int x;` then `x` is default-initialized, which for `int` means "no initialization is performed", because it's a POD type. If you write `int x = int()`, which is what containers do (except it's `T x = T()` for containers, because they are templates) then `x` is initialized to integer zero.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. When you use the `[]`-operator on a map and no element with the desired key exists, a new element is inserted which is value-initialized. For an integer, this means initialized to zero.

Answer (score 3):

> does it work for all cases?

For all cases, a new key will be associated with a value initialized to `T()`.

When `T` is a built-in or [Plain Old Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) type, such as `int` or `double`, that evaluates to zero.

When `T` is a class, the map will attempt to call the empty constructor.

Comment: If this class has a default constructor. Otherwise it will fail to compile.